# Lisp Macro - how enter a type correctly

Tags: json, macros, lisp

I'm new to macros and struggling with a requirement in a macro of JSON-RPC.

It is asking for a type and I don't know how to enter it correctly.

```
(defmacro defun-json-rpc (name type lambda-list &body body)
  "Defines a function and registers it as a json-rpc target."   
   (unless (json-rpc-encoding-p type)    
   (error "New version of defun-json-rpc requires a TYPE argument"))   
  `(progn    
     (defun ,name ,lambda-list ,@body)   
     (export-as-json-rpc ',name (lisp-to-camel-case (symbol-name ',name)) ,type)))
```

A piece of sample code I found follows, but it does not contain the type argument:

```
(json-rpc:defun-json-rpc add (x y)
  (+ x y))
```

How would I enter the type?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(unless (json-rpc-encoding-p type) (error ...))`?

Comment: Corrected that in question.  Code I'm using has it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  It is a JSON-RPC specific keyword, not a lisp type.  I just needed to look at  json-rpc-encoding-p to see that only 3 keywords are valid.

```
(defgeneric json-rpc-encoding-p (keyword)
  (:documentation "Is KEYWORD a valid JSON-RPC value encoding?")
  (:method (keyword)
     "Default is no."
     (declare (ignore keyword))
      nil)
  ;;; built-in methods
  (:method ((keyword (eql :guessing)))
    t)
  (:method ((keyword (eql :streaming)))
    t)
  (:method ((keyword (eql :explicit)))
    t))
```

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as accepted.  It might help other users if you can elaborate on it a bit, too.